# jQuery UI beforeShowDay in inline datepicker crashing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Fairly straight question:

If I have an inline datepicker (call .datepicker() on a div instead of an input) and use the beforeShowDay function, everything breaks.

I've created a jsFiddle here so you can test it:
http://jsfiddle.net/MBwSe/1/

The beforeShowDay function works for the first 4 days to me (jul 29 to aug 01 2012) and then breaks on aug 02 2012 with this error:

```
TypeError: daySettings is undefined
[Break On This Error]   
line 8827

var unselectable = (otherMonth && !selectOtherMonths) || !daySettings[0] ||
```

Any ideas what's going on? Driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return an array from `beforeShowDay`. From the docs:

> The function takes a date as a parameter and **must return an array** with
>   [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is
>   selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or "" for the default
>   presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is
>   called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

**Modified Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MBwSe/2/

Comment: Jesus Christ... thanks. There are some other problems with my code, but are unrelated... but this fixed this particular problem. Thank you!