# issue with datepicker TypeError: daySettings is undefined unselectable = (otherMonth && !selectOtherMonths) || !daySettings[0] ||

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

hi i have a issue with date picker i have a var (string) with "yes" if i want to block a day for all period otherwise if i have "" i don't want to block

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var sunday = ""; // here use a called php to get a value from db ex. 
            "<?php print get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_domenica", true); ?>";
        var monday = "";
        var tuesday = "yes";
        var wednesday = "";
        var thursday  = "";
        var friday = "";
        var saturday = "yes";


        jQuery('#dateEscluseEventCalendar').datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(),
            beforeShowDay: function (day) {
                var day = day.getDay();
                var closeDays = [[sunday],[monday],[tuesday],
                [wednesday],[thursday],[friday],[saturday]];
                for (var i = 0; i < closeDays.length; i++){
                    if (day == i && closeDays[i][0]== "yes" ) 
                        return [false]; 

                }

        }});

});
```

bute the error in console is:

```
TypeError: daySettings is undefined unselectable = (otherMonth && !
selectOtherMonths)|| !daySettings[0] ||
```

do you have a solution??
thanks for your time :)

Comment: See below link...I think ,You got answer::
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064606/jquery-ui-beforeshowday-in-inline-datepicker-crashing